# state management in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, state-management

I am new to windows phone 7.

I have a .xaml page, in that i have lot of TextBoxes and DatePickers to enter User data, If he Submit form i am inserting User data in to Database. But my problem is, in that form i have Country Button if he clicks  on that button i am going to different page, in that page he can select Country then i am returning back to the previous form. While returning to Previous page data entered by user will be gone. But here i need to maintain the State(date entered by user should reappear on Form)  in that page.

Ho can i do this in Windows Phone 7?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the ListPicker from [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/75888) for choosing the Country. This will not delete your control states

Answer (score 1):

You will want to store this data in the page state.  This way you can reconstruct the page when it is navigated to and also after the application is suspended.  Otherwise, after your app is tombstoned you will lose this data and after your app rehydrates the user will have to enter it again.  If you save it to the page state, you can restore the page to make it appear as if tombstoning never occurred.

There is a lot of [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967548%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) on msdn to help you manage application state.